# How to search samsung messages with intent (A21s)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, samsung-galaxy

***First of all I'm not a android developer***. I'm trying to search Samsung's default messages app with intent. So far no result. I can open search box with `com.samsung.android.messaging.ui.view.search.SearchActivity` but ***can't pass data to search for***.
In normal android sms app I can transfer **HashMap** `[{intent_extra_data_key: Hello World}][1]` to `com.android.mms.ui.SearchActivity` and everything works normally.

Any idea how can I search sms with intent? I still have the ability to open and paste data but I want to do it with intent. Here is the Manifest file of the [app](https://pastebin.com/6i4UTnSY) and [apk](https://samsung-messages.en.uptodown.com/android/download/3561244).

Answer (score -1):

Just put the data as extras in that intent. Like `indent.putExtra("key","data");` You can retrive data using `indent.getStringExtra("key","defValue");` . **I am telling you general way of passing data, I am not sure wheather it work on tasker or not**.

Comment: What do you mean by why I want to search? As I said I'm not android developer and I'm using Tasker, Automate or FooView to start app with intent, My friend want to know If specific transaction id was sent to her or not, It's faster than regular way and I made every other function up and ready, just want to know how to search to increase speed.

Comment: Do you mean that you want tasker to search for you in that app ?

Comment: for example 0123456789 is a transaction id, my friend has to open sms app and search manually, retrive data, organize and send confirmation. Currently I can use intent to directly open search box and paste that id, I would like to search without pasting, I enclosed manifest and apk

Comment: Show me your code for that intent, also show Manifiest.xml

Comment: In tasker or any other app you can launch app with intent like `com.samsung.android.messaging.ui.view.search.SearchActivity`. Now I want to know how can I pass data here, I already added Manifest, Click link named app and apk for actual apk.

Comment: I have updated the answer, is that helpful ?